# Check whether a string contains a numeric/digit/number in python

Tags: python, string, digit

I have a string, and i need to check whether it contains a `number/digit at the end` of the string, and need to increment that `number/digit` at the end of the string with `+1`

I will get the strings as below

```
string2  = suppose_name_1
string3  = suppose_name_22
string4  = supp22ose45_na56me_45
```

for sure i will get the string in the above format like suppose_somthing + `Underscore` + `digits`

So from the above strings

1. I need to check whether a string contains a number/digit at the end of the string after underscore
2. If it contains then need to increment that with `+1` like below

   string2  = suppose_name_**2**

   string3  = suppose_name_**23**

   string4  = supp22ose45_na56me_**46**

How can we do this in python by using regular expressions or something, but that should be very fast.

I have done something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232474/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-if-string-contains-digits), but want to implement with re that will be very fast , so approached SO

`Edit:` 
sorry din't mentioned above

Sometimes it contains just `something_name` without integer, hence i need to check whether it contains a number in it first

Comment: You said that your strings will be for sure in that format? Then why should you check whether the string ends with digits or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex. You can just use simple `str.replace`:

```
>>> s = 'suppose_name_1'
>>> index = s.rfind('_')  # Last index of '_'
>>> s.replace(s[index+1:], str(int(s[index+1:]) + 1))
'suppose_name_2'
```

If you need to first check whether you have digits at the end, you can check that using `str.isdigit()` method:

```
>>> s = 'suppose_name'
>>> 
>>> index = s.rfind('_')
>>> if s[index+1:].isdigit():
        s = s.replace(s[index+1:], str(int(s[index+1:]) + 1))


>>> s
'suppose_name'
```

Comment: k rohit, but sorry i dint mentioned in the question sometimes i will get only suppose_name without number at the end, so first i need to check whether it contains integer in it.

Answer (score 2):

How about using regular expressions:

```
import re

def process_string(s):
    try:
        part1, part2 = re.search('^(.*_)(\d+)$', s).groups()
        part2 = str(int(part2) + 1)
        return part1 + part2 
    except AttributeError:
        return s

print process_string("suppose_name_1")
print process_string("suppose_name_22")
print process_string("supp22ose45_na56me_45")

print process_string("suppose_name")
```

prints:

```
suppose_name_2
suppose_name_23
supp22ose45_na56me_46
suppose_name
```

FYI, there is nothing wrong or scary with using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's short regex solution that increments the number with re.sub(...):

```
from re import sub

string2  = 'suppose_name_1'
string3  = 'suppose_name_22'
string4  = 'supp22ose45_na56me_45'
print [sub(r'^(?P<pretext>.*_)(?P<number>\d+)$', lambda x : '%s%d' % (x.group('pretext'), int(x.group('number')) + 1), s) for s in (string2, string3, string4)]
```

and the output:

```
['suppose_name_2', 'suppose_name_23', 'supp22ose45_na56me_46']
```

The easier to read version would be something like this:

```
from re import sub

string2  = 'suppose_name_1'
string3  = 'suppose_name_22'
string4  = 'supp22ose45_na56me_45'
regex = r'^(?P<pretext>.*_)(?P<number>\d+)$'

def increment(matchObject):
    return '%s%d' % (matchObject.group('pretext'), int(matchObject.group('number')) + 1)

for s in (string2, string3, string4):
    print sub(regex, increment, s)
```

and the output:

```
suppose_name_2
suppose_name_23
supp22ose45_na56me_46
```